# formsubmit.co emails don't always arrive

Tags: captcha

It is happening to me that some people contact me by phone...because I have not responded to their email messages.
I go to the website... and there are times when sending it asks me for the captcha... and the emails arrive..., but there are other times when it doesn't ask me for the captcha and although the system indicates that it was sent... it doesn't I get the emails.
Even from other computers, on the first attempt I don't get the messages, coinciding with the fact that it doesn't ask me for a captcha.
(If you request captcha the messages arrive perfectly)

I clarify that I never disabled the captcha.

How can this be resolved?
Thank you

I really don't know how to solve it because sometimes it works perfectly but other times it doesn't...
In my case I can no longer know if any client believes that I did not want to respond to them... because I never received the email.
Let's say you take it as if it were spam... but it is not...